# An application that works on all iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am new at Xcode, I did everything on Android, now, it's the iPhones turn.

I start:

- Xcode with "Create a new Xcode project"
- "Choose a template for your new project: Single View Application" and filled the info. 
  [[image]

Now I have a problem:

- I did everything so it work on all "iPhones" (as in image 2) but I don't know if I'm not right or wrong :).

[[image]

- I plugged in an iPhone 4 but I don't know if I can use it *now* or not.

Please help :)

Comment: Does it run on your iPhone?  If not, what errors do you see?

Comment: It runs well on the iPhnoe 4 but when I change from the "plugged" iPhone 4, to the screen of iPhone 6, the screen looks smaller.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the answer is to learn about autolayout.  Here's a starting point: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read it and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about Size Classes. It allows you to create layouts for different scenarios as rotating the phone. In the last image you are changing the Size Classes.

Comment: I have a small question if you may, concerning this, if I put an image and a button each are put in the sides on iPhone 4, will it do the same in iPhone 5? Or 6? http://oi64.tinypic.com/whfdyg.jpg

Comment: No, you should define constraints. Explore the small menus at the right bottom corner of the main storyboard.

Comment: Ok, that changes things, I'll be back then.